# How to filter pandas DataFrames that have columns with lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas DataFrame that contains lists in some columns:

```
col1    col2      col3
a       [1]       [a,b]
b       [1,2,3]   [a,c]
b       [1,2,3]   [b,c]
b       [1,3]     [b,c]
```

I want to get a subset of this DataFrame. In this subset the `col2` should contain `1` and `2`, and `col3` should contain `a`.

In my example the answer should be:

```
col1    col2      col3
b       [1,2,3]   [a,c]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
df[df["col2"].str.contains("1,2", na=False)]
```

How can I solve my task?

Comment: Are the values lists or strings?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny: `type(df["col2"][0])` returns `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
df['bool'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if 1 in x['col2'] and 2 in x['col2'] and 'a' in x['col3'] 
else False, axis=1)
df_subset = df.loc[df['bool'] == True, :]
del df_subset['bool']
print(df_subset)
```

First added a boolean column using `apply` whether the conditions match and then filtering based on that column

Answer (score 1):

You can find the subset with set operations

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: not {1, 2, 'a'} - (set(x.col2) | set(x.col3)), axis=1)]
```

Out:

```
  col1       col2    col3
1    b  [1, 2, 3]  [a, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline approach
Suppose `df` is the original data frame

```
df[[True if 1 in i and 2 in i and "a" in j else False for i,j in zip(df.col2,df.col3) ]]
```

Can solve the problem

You can modify the logic as required